# words 2016 as default instead of words 2013

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-word-2016

I have two version of Microsoft words 2013 and 2016, the reason I got both version somehow when I upgrade to words 2016 , the 2013 version is not deleted. so every default words (.docx) files still open by default in words 2013 not 2016.

how to make words 2016 as default words program instead of 2013? I am using Microsoft Windows 10, has tried to change directly on default apps, but it only shows words program with no specification either words 2013 or 2016.

Comment: What operating system.  How you change the default program for an extensive has remained unchanged even if your using Windows 10.  You would have to manually chnage the default from Word 2016 to Word 2013.  Another option would be to uninstall both, install 2016, then install 2013.  Question doesn’t have enough information to submit a quality answer

Comment: edited,  what I want is using 2016 as default, try that to but somehow it still went to words 2013

Comment: Your title says “Office 2013 default instead” which reads to me the current default is Office 2016 and you want it to be Office 2013.  Why don’t you just uninstall Office 2013?  You have to manually select the specific Word executable you want to use.  As previously stated.  Just uninstall both and install the one you want to be the default last.

Comment: my mistake, if I uninstall office 2013, office 2016 will not work which is very weird. if I install/repair office 2016 it will also install office 2013. thus not solving the problem

Comment: Sounds like you have not actually installed Office 2016.  Office 2016 is a separate and independent product from Office 2013.  How are you installing Office 2016?  Offline ISO/physical disk/online installation

Comment: online installation, if I remember correctly I clicked upgrade in office 365 when there is an offer to do so. I subscribed the office 365 program.

Comment: There are two programs that Office 365.  One is entirely online and only exists in the cloud, the other is a subscription, to Office.  So which one are you using?  The subscription is to the current version of Office, and Office 2013, has not been the current version for 6 years.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74899/discussion-between-ramhound-and-whale-steward).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so to fix it, quite easy :

1. go to add or remove program
2. uninstall words 2013
3. go to office 2016 and select modify > repair
4. DONE!!!

if you don't select repair, office 2016 cannot be used (my experience). it seems my previous attempt is using installation to repair it and try to re-install it, which causing the problem.